# polymorphism and inheritance in objective-c example

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to understand polymorphism and inheritance.  I don't have too much experience in it.  What I'm basically trying to do is have a generic BaseFileLogic class that can open a file from the bundle.  I have subclasses of the BaseFileLogic class that have the file name as a constant for those specific subclasses.  The idea was basically for someone who dragged a file name I specify from iTunes sharing, I could open the file and parse it for my different object types.  So my BaseFileLogic class is pretty simple with a class and designated initializer:

```
- (id)initWithFileName:(NSString *)fileName fileLocation:(FileLocation)fileLocation {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _currentFile = fileName;

        NSString *filePath = nil;
        if (fileLocation == FileLocationBundle) {
            filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"csv"];
        }
        else {
            filePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:_currentFile];            
        }

        _parser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVFile:filePath];
        _parser.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (id)baseFileLogicWithFileName:(NSString *)fileName fileLocation:(FileLocation)fileLocation {
    return [[CRBaseFileLogic alloc] initWithFileName:fileName fileLocation:fileLocation ];
}
```

Now in my RoastLogic class, I have this so far:

```
@interface CRRoastFileLogic : CRBaseFileLogic

+ (id)roastFileLogicFromFileLocation:(FileLocation)fileLocation;

@end
```

@implementation CRRoastFileLogic

```
+ (id)roastFileLogicFromFileLocation:(FileLocation)fileLocation {
CRBaseFileLogic *cr = [CRBaseFileLogic baseFileLogicWithFileName:(NSString *)kRoastFileName fileLocation:fileLocation];
    NSLog(@"cr: %@", [cr description]);
    return cr;
}
@end
```

When I print out the description, the cr object is of type CRBaseFileLogic.  I guess at this part I'm confused because I want to create an instance of CRRoastFileLogic, but use methods that I have declared in the superclass.  How is inheritance /polymorphism supposed to work?

Comment: Polymorphism has a slightly different meaning in Objective-C than in C++, because it is not strong typed, lots of stuff (instance types, method implementations) are determined at runtime. I recommend you research the Apple documentation or other Objective-C material where it explains how the runtime determines which method implementation to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this method

```
+ (id)baseFileLogicWithFileName:(NSString *)fileName fileLocation:(FileLocation)fileLocation {
    return [[CRBaseFileLogic alloc] initWithFileName:fileName fileLocation:fileLocation ];
}
```

you have the problem. Because it always return an instance of `CRBaseFileLogic`

so change it like this should solve the problem

```
+ (id)baseFileLogicWithFileName:(NSString *)fileName fileLocation:(FileLocation)fileLocation {
    return [[self alloc] initWithFileName:fileName fileLocation:fileLocation ];
}
```

then the `self` will be `CRRoastFileLogic` if you call it like `[CRRoastFileLogic baseFileLogicWithFileName...]`